# Displaying content from an entity reference in a view

Tags: blocks, views

I have a node type, Medical Group, that has an entity reference field (field_accreditation) to another node type, Accreditation.

I would like to create a block to display on each Medical Group page that displays the Accreditation for that particular Medical Group.

I also need to provide a default value when the block is placed on a page that does not have an Accreditation field.

I've tried adding a relationship and then using that as a contextual filter, but that doesn't seem to work. Any advice or steps to go about this?

[image: Fields so far]

Answer (score 0):

- Remove current contextual filter and relationship
- In contextual filter add nid.
- In its configuration select raw value from URL, then select argument number which is your nid form url
- Now you can also set default value in this configuration
- In block display setting show your block on your content type.